# Showing commutator subgroup is a subgroup

Tags: group-theory

Now, the common introduction question to a commutator subgroup $G'$ is showing that it is normal in the group $G$. However, I'm having a problem with something even more basic than this.

Let $[a,b],[c,d] \in G'$,

Then we have:

$[a,b][c,d]=a^{-1}b^{-1}abc^{-1}d^{-1}cd$

I don't see an easy to conclude that this of the form $[g,h]=g^{-1}h^{-1}gh$ for $g,h \in G$.

What am i missing here?

$G' \neq \{ a^{-1}b^{-1}ab : a,b \in G \}$

$G' = \{ \langle a^{-1}b^{-1}ab \rangle : a,b \in G\}$

Comment: How are you defining the commutator subgroup?  The [standard definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutator_subgroup) says it is the subgroup generated by commutators.  Once can also define it to be any word in the elements of $G$ that has a rearrangement that multiplies to the identity, but that's not standard (I believe).

Comment: In general, the product of two commutator elements is not a commutator

Comment: Oh. Then what is the operation that makes $G'$ a group?

Comment: It's the product inherited from $G$, of course.

Comment: But according to Hagen, this would mean $G'$ is not closed under the binary operation of G.

Comment: No.  $G'$ is the subgroup generated by commutators, it is not the set of commutators (which, as you remark, is generally not closed under multiplication).

Comment: OOOOOOOH wow. Thanks! So I defind $G'$ wrong above. Okay

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note: $$\boxed{G'=\langle\{ [a, b]\mid a,b\in G\}\rangle.}$$ Hence for $[f,g], [h, k]\in G'$ with $f,g,h,k\in G$, we have that $[f,g][h,k]\in G'$, since it is a product of some generators of the subgroup.

More generally, for $\mathfrak{g}=\prod_{i\in I}[g_i, g'_i]$ and $\mathfrak{h}=\prod_{j\in J}[h_j, h'_j]$ belonging to $G'$, where $I$ and $J$ are some index sets for some element sequences $(g_i), (g'_i)\in G^I$ and $(h_j), (h'_j)\in G^J$, we have that

\begin{align}
\mathfrak{g}\mathfrak{h}&=\prod_{i\in I}[g_i, g'_i]\prod_{j\in J}[h_j, h'_j] \tag{1} \\
&=\prod_{\ell\in L}[f_\ell, f'_\ell],
\end{align}

where $L$ and the sequences $(f_\ell), (f'_\ell)\in G^L$ run through the commutators in $(1)$ in order; that is, one notices that it is a product of commutators as it is the product of two products of commutators.

As for showing it's a subgroup, I suggest the "two-step subgroup lemma". However, [as pointed out in the comments below](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3096844/showing-commutator-subgroup-is-a-subgroup/3096869#comment6384003_3096869), it is much better to prove that the group $\langle X\rangle$ generated by a subset $X$ of a group $G$ with respect to the operation of $G$ is a subgroup of $G$ *in general*.

---

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/141888/104041) is about how to show the subgroup is normal.

Comment: If it is defined as “the subgroup generated by...” then why would you need to show it is a subgroup? Did you mean “As for showing it’s a *normal* subgroup”?

Comment: Well, for the sake of rigour, some of us prefer to check whether such definitions make sense. I think what I have typed in this answer is illustrative, at least, of how one works with $G'$ and what the general element of $G'$ is. I'll add a note giving a hint on how to prove that the subgroup is normal.

Comment: D'you think that's a fair comment of mine, @ArturoMagidin? You seem more experienced than I am so your feedback would be appreciated $\ddot\smile$

Comment: There are two definitions of "the subgroup of group $G$ generated by subset $X$ of $G$". One is the intersection of all subgroups of $G$ containing $X$, and the other is the set of all products of elements of $X$ and their inverses.  The first of these clearly does define a subgroup of $G$ and then you need to prove that the two definitions are equivalent. It is preferable to do all of that in a general setting, since then it becomes unnecessary to prove that you are defining a subgroup in specific cases. For normality, it is  easier to prove the stronger property that $G'$ is  characteristic.

Comment: I've edited my answer, @DerekHolt. Thank you :)

Comment: It would be very poor nomenclature if “the subgroup generated” created an object that was not in fact a subgroup...

Comment: For general comments along the lines of Derek Holt’s comment, see this [prior answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/54172/the-sigma-algebra-of-subsets-of-x-generated-by-a-set-mathcala-is-the-s/54334#54334).