# how to prove that all the homomorphisms from $~G\to K~$ are from specific form

Tags: abstract-algebra, symmetric-groups, cyclic-groups, normal-subgroups, group-homomorphism

I tried to solve an exercise from a previous test asking "find all the homomorphisms from $~S_4~$ to $~Z_4~$ and show that those are all of them"

In the solution they used homo' such that:

$\phi(s)=0~$ if $~s~$ is in $~A_4$

$\phi(s)=2~$ if $~s~$ is not in $~A_4$

and because $~A_4~$ is contained in the Kernell they said that those are all the homo'there are  can please someone explain to me why is that true?

Perhaps I didn't understand the solution?

thank you!

Comment: That's not the only homomorphism. You also have the trivial homomorphism, that sends every element to $0$. And don't you mean $\phi(s)=2$ if $s$ is not in $A_4$? Or do you want homomorphisms to $\mathbb{Z}_2$ and not $\mathbb{Z}_4$? Because otherwise, you can take two elements $s_1$ and $s_2$ which are not in $A_4$ and get $\phi(s_1)+\phi(s_2)=2\neq\phi(s_1s_2)$, since no element has image $2$, so it would not be a homomorphism.

Comment: yes, i meant phi(s) = 2, thank you.

but how do i show that those two are the only one's there are?

Answer (score 2):

Well, first things first, that is not the only homomorphism. You also have the homomorphism that takes every element to $0$.

That justification seems to be using the fact that $A_4$ is the [commutator subgroup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutator_subgroup) of $S_4$. You can see a proof of this fact [here](https://coolnumbers.wordpress.com/2011/10/20/the-commutator-subgroup-of-s_n/).

Now, given an arbitrary group $G$, the commutator subgroup is usually denoted $[G,G]$ and you can [show that it's a normal subgroup of $G$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/141888/how-to-show-that-the-commutator-subgroup-is-a-normal-subgroup). The quotient $G/[G,G]$ is called the abelianization of $G$ and it has the following [universal property](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Universal_Property_of_Abelianization_of_Group):

Given an abelian group $H$ and a homomorphism $f:G\to H$, there exists a unique homomorphism $g:G/[G,G]\to H$ such that $f=g\circ\pi$ where $\pi:G\to G/[G,G]$ is the projection. This universal property gives you bijection between homomorphisms $G\to H$ and $G/[G,G]\to H$ when $H$ is abelian.

In your specific case, where $G=S_4$, $[G,G]=A_4$ and $H=\mathbb{Z}_4$, you can show that $S_4/A_4\cong\mathbb{Z}_2$, so there are as many homomorphisms $S_4\to\mathbb{Z}_4$ as $\mathbb{Z}_2\to\mathbb{Z}_4$. Clearly there are only two homomorphisms $\mathbb{Z}_2\to\mathbb{Z}_4$, since you either send $1$ to $0$ or $2$. This already proves the claim, but you can further check that these correspond, by the universal property, to the trivial homomorphism and the non-trivial one that you defined, respectively.

Final comment: these are all basic results in algebra, so, from what you wrote in your question, they probably summed up all of this to "$A_4$ must be in the kernel of your homomorphism $f$", which is equivalent to saying that there exists another homomorphism $g:S_4/A_4\to\mathbb{Z}_4$ such that $f=g\circ\pi$.

I hope this helps.

Comment: wow! thank you very much!