# How does the homomorphism help in the normality of the commutator subgroup?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-homomorphism

This is some sort of follow up question to https://math.stackexchange.com/q/141901.

I understand that to show the normality of the commutator subgroup it is enough to show that $g[a,b]g^{-1}$ is in the commutator subgroup.

In the above answer and in many articles I read, comes the homomorphism part in the proof.
I have been processing it for hours but I really don't understand how we draw the conclusion.

As far as I understand it, we define the homomorphism as $f(x)=gxg^{-1}$ and use the fact that $f([x,y])=[f(x),f(y)]$. Why and how do we use this, and why the equality holds true and how do arrive to the desired conclusion.

I would be really thankful for help. Clearly I am missing something or have problems with basic idea of homomorphism.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you agree that $f$ is a homomorphism? If so, then $f([x,y])=f(xyx^{-1}y^{-1})=f(x)f(y)f(x)^{-1}f(y)^{-1}=[f(x),f(y)]$. In particular, $g[x,y]g^{-1}=f([x,y])=[f(x),f(y)]$ is some commutator, so it is in the commutator subgroup. If you really struggle to process this part, you can check by hand (it’s not as enlightening) that $g[x,y]g^{-1}=[gxg^{-1},gyg^{-1}]$.

Comment: Everything very clear, thank you a lot.

Comment: @Mindlack do you also maybe know how can I use this result in the groups of inner automorphisms being a normal subgroup of the automorphisms.

Comment: Let $\psi$ be an automorphism of a group $G$; let $g \in G$ and let $c_g: h \in G \longmapsto ghg^{-1}$. Then you want to show that $\psi \circ c_g \circ \psi^{-1}$ is an inner automorphism. But, if $x \in G$, can you compute $\psi(c_g(\psi^{-1}(x)))$?